# Cache-Control HTTP Headers precedence

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

I've read this excellent article about Cache-Control HTTP Headers: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

I was wondering what would happen with the following header:

`Cache-Control: no-store, public`

Would the public header take precedence over the no-store header, or vice versa?

Would the header that takes precedence vary from one browser to another?

I understand that to have both no-store and public Cache-Control headers may not be advisable, but for arguments sake what would happen if they were both present.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [the RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234). Given:

> ```
> Cache-Control: no-store, public
> ```

`no-store` is the Response Cache-Control Directive ([RFC 7234, Section 5.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2)). It states that the response should not be stored.

`public` is an **extension**.

> The Cache-Control header field can be extended through the use of one
> or more cache-extension tokens, each with an optional value.  A cache
> MUST ignore unrecognized cache directives.

Since `public` isn't a known extension to `no-store`, it is ignored.

Comment: Although it is true `no-store` takes precedence (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57273065/9314312)), it is false that the `public` directive is a `cache-control` extension. `immutable`, `stale-while-revalidate` and `stale-if-error`, those are extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Find some of the main code regarding this question from [Google Chrome Browser](http://chromium-browser-source.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome_android.v18.0.1025123.tgz) below.

```
isPubliclyCacheable: function(resource)
{
    if (this._isExplicitlyNonCacheable(resource))
        return false;

    if (this.responseHeaderMatch(resource, "Cache-Control", "public"))
        return true;

    return resource.url.indexOf("?") == -1 && !this.responseHeaderMatch(resource, "Cache-Control", "private");
}


_isExplicitlyNonCacheable: function(resource)
{
    var hasExplicitExp = this.hasExplicitExpiration(resource);
    return this.responseHeaderMatch(resource, "Cache-Control", "(no-cache|no-store|must-revalidate)") ||
        this.responseHeaderMatch(resource, "Pragma", "no-cache") ||
        (hasExplicitExp && !this.freshnessLifetimeGreaterThan(resource, 0)) ||
        (!hasExplicitExp && resource.url && resource.url.indexOf("?") >= 0) ||
        (!hasExplicitExp && !this.isCacheableResource(resource));
}
```

According to the code some of the directives have more priority than the other and "no-store" is among them so in your case (Cache-Control: "public, no-store" or "no-store, public") no-store will get higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

I've shortened down the section of the HTTP Caching specification that relates to your use case (See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3):

> A cache **MUST NOT store a response** to any request, **unless**:
>
> the **"no-store"** cache directive (see Section 5.2) **does not appear**
> in request or response header fields, **and**
>
> the response either:
>
> contains a Cache Control Extension (see Section 5.2.3) that
> allows it to be cached, or contains a public response directive (see Section 5.2.2.5).
>
> contains a **public** response directive (see Section 5.2.2.5).

In short, `no-store` takes precedence over `public`.